# How to pass values into an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I get values from php. In label values are like: `"a","b","c","d"` and in amount = `10,20,30,40`.

```
var label = <?php echo json_encode($label ); ?>;
var amount = <?php echo json_encode($Amount ); ?>;
```

Now I want to combine these values into an object like this:

```
{ x: "label", y: amount }
```

in JavaScript.
How I can do this?

Comment: How does your markup look like ? Grabbing 2 different arrays is not very great approach.. Better get `label => value` object!

Comment: `var op=[];values.forEach(function(val,index){ op.push({x:val,y:amount[index];}); });`

Comment: Why not in PHP? `array_combine($label, $amount)`

Answer (score 0):

[Array combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) php function does exactly this

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to decide whether you want to combine the values on the PHP side or on JavaScript side.

Next, once you have `label` and `value`, you can add those to your object like this:

```
var obj = {};
...
obj.x = label;
obj.y = amount;
```

or, if what you want is really

```
{ label: amount, label2: amount2 }
```

then you have to use syntax like this:

```
obj[label] = value;
```

But if it's good enough for you to create such an object on the back-end (using PHP), then see Denis' answer (if you want `{ label: amount, label2: amount2 }` like stuff; otherwise use just `$ar["x"] = $label; $ar["y"] = $amount`).

But as you can see, your question has way too many possible interpretations, so please make it clearer.